# jquery :not() selector inside delegated event

Tags: jquery

I tried to use the `:not()` selector inside an delegated event like

```
 $('#sidebar-nav').on('click', 'a.documents:not(span)', function(e){

 // code

 });
```

but it's not working. So how to write delegated click event in order to select the link but not the `<span>` element inside it?
The Event has to be delegated because all links are added dynamically.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not working as expected because the selector `a.documents:not(span)` will select anchor elements with a class of `.documents` that are *not* `span` elements (which means that none of the elements will be negated since none of the anchor elements are `span` elements).

In other words, the `:not()` pseudo class doesn't suppress the event from being fired, it merely negates anchor elements that are `span` elements from being selected (which means that it isn't doing anything at all).

You could check if `event.target` is equal to `event.currentTarget` in order to determine if the anchor element is being clicked (and not the other descendant elements):

```
$('#sidebar-nav').on('click', 'a.documents', function(event) {
  if (event.target === event.currentTarget) {
    console.log('event.target is the anchor element and not the span.')
  }
});
```

Where `event.currentTarget` references the element that the event listener is currently attached to (which is the anchor element); and `event.target` references the element that triggered the click event.

---

Alternatively, another option is to stop event propagation on the descendant `span` elements in order to prevent the click event from being fired:

```
$('#sidebar-nav').on('click', 'a.documents', function(event) {
  console.log('Clicked the anchor, not the span.')
});
$('#sidebar-nav').on('click', 'a.documents span', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I'd suggest going with the first option since it's definitely cleaner.

Comment: I remember that years ago a similar thing was possible with .delegate(). Btw, first solution is my case. Great thanks!